# Alternative to sprintf() for bytes buffer in C

Tags: sql, c, string, printf, buffer

Hello guys I have an issue when i try to put my bytes buffer into a sql buffer for sqlite3.c.

For example, I have this buffer:

```
static unsigned char bytes_buffer[] = {
        0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x4b, 0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x03, 0x06, 0x07, 0x2a, 0x86,
        0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x02, 0x01, 0x30, 0x81, 0xf7, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x30,
        0x2c, 0x06, 0x07, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x21,
        0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00}
```

My function to add this info into a sqlite3 query and insert into my database is the following:

```
    unsigned char *sql=(unsigned char *)malloc((size_t)(sizeof(unsigned char)*SQL_SIZE));
    sprintf(sql,"UPDATE table SET buffer='%s', WHERE id=%d",bytes_buffer,id);
    printf("SQL: %s\n",sql);
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        return SQLITE_ERROR;
    }
    else
        return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

The problem is when i try to show the query content, because in the buffer parameter sprintf() stops when a null character (0x00) appears. I need a function similar to sprintf() where I can manage the parameters size. I tried snprintf() and also fails. Thank you so much.

Comment: you can try using sqlite3_bind_blob function to bind the binary buffer to a prepared statement and then execute the statement, this would allow you to insert the binary buffer into the database without having to convert it to a string.

Comment: @sendix,  What text output, exactly, would you like to see for `bytes_buffer[] = 0x30, 0x82, 0x01,...`

Comment: Every buffer bytes values, at now it stops at 0x21 cause the next bytes are null char. I have the length saved in other variable to indicate when to stop if the function demands it